# Which is better vue-native or nativescript-vue?

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue, vue-native

I would like to start a mobile app with VueJS. Can anyone please suggest which Framework I can choose between [vue-native](https://vue-native.io/) or **[nativescript-vue](https://nativescript-vue.org/)**?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I have written sample apps of both and I feel native script is better since designing native components with native script is some what similar with HTML tags.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Vue-Native is nothing but a wrapper around ReactNative. So the question becomes **ReactNative** vs **NativeScript**?

In my opinion, it's **NativeScript**.

- Supports frameworks like Angular & Vue
- Works with Core JavaScript / TypeScript too
- Better code sharing
- 100% access to native apis

**ReactNative** got a huge community and range of plugins, but the problem beings when you want to customise. Every app is unique in it's own way, it becomes really hard to customise a plugin for your own needs at least until you have good exposure to Objective C / Java and handle your own forks etc.,

With **NativeScript** you can always access the native objects & apis form JavaScript, simply write overrides on plugins within your project if you want to customise anything.

Here are few blog posts & videos those compare these frameworks.

- [Would Airbnb Have Fared Better With NativeScript Instead of React Native?](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/would-airbnb-have-fared-better-with-nativescript-instead-of-react-native)
- [ReactNative vs NativeScript](https://youtu.be/rb8smP_xTTY?t=220)

Comment: Thank you manoj.actully sample apps of both and I too feel native script is better since designing native components with native script is some what similar with HTML tags.

Comment: That means that Vue-Native has the same React Native power but in a Vue manner implemented? Or are there things that can be done in React Native that cannot in Vue-Native?

Comment: It may be possible but I wouldn't personally suggest Vue Native as it's maintained by a third party. As of today, last activity on the repo was over 4 months ago.

Answer (score 12):

As @Manoj mentioned about the biggest advantage of using Nativescript is : You can access all the native elements and apis from Javascript.

I think another plus is the ability to create a code-sharing project. New Vue CLI plugin enables code sharing between web and mobile.There’s nothing quite as awesome as watching your web, iOS and Android app all spinning up at once with the same codebase.

You can further read on nativescript [blog](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/code-sharing-with-nativescript-vue) and [here](https://github.com/jlooper/mandala-me) is the sample project.

Answer (score 2):

You should also look into simply wrapping your Vue app with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). I was required recently to build a mobile app and went through both vue-native & nativescript-vue, eventually ending up with Cordova.

At a basic level, you can wrap any static website and compile it as an android or ios app. If you need native elements you can also do so once Cordova fires the 'deviceready' event.