# Build Native Apps using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript

I'm new in javascript, specially in vue js. I found 3 "framework" *cmiiw* to build native apps using vue.js.
1. Native Script (using vue.js) -> https://www.nativescript.org
2. Vue Native -> https://vue-native.io/
3. NativeScript-Vue -> https://nativescript-vue.org/

What your opinion about this 3 "framework"? Which one is the best to build native apps.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Nativescript and Nativescript-Vue you are pointing are exactly same. Vue-Native is based on ReactNative. So you are likely to ask Nativescript vs ReactNative - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867122/which-is-better-vue-native-or-nativescript-vue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I think NativeScript is best**

> It backed by Telerik, a Progress Software company, you’re able to
>   build native Android and native iOS applications using JavaScript,
>   TypeScript, or a variety of frameworks such as Angular and Vue.js.
>
> What makes NativeScript particularly cool is how native platform APIs
>   are accessed and how the source code is transpiled.
>
> By leveraging the V8 JavaScript engine for Android and JavaScriptCore
>   for iOS, all device APIs are directly accessible from JavaScript code.
>   This removes the necessity of plugins as well as the need to know
>   Java, Objective-C, and Swift. At compile time, all XML components are
>   transpiled to native Android and iOS components before being bundled
>   as an application binary. No WebView is involved when running
>   NativeScript applications, unless of course you decide to include one.
>   By using native components, the applications can run with maximum
>   performance.

[Source](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/04/3-best-frameworks-mobile-app-development-2018/)